# Linking to document returned from an API

Tags: javascript, azure, axios

I have an API call (azure function) that is returning a HttpResponseMessage

```
var result = await StorageHelper.GetFileFromStorage(filePath);
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new ByteArrayContent(result.DocumentAsByteArray)
};

response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(result.ContentType);

return response;
```

I'm digesting this using the below javascript

```
axios
    .get(
        `${config.apiGatewayURL}/download-file/${file}`)
    .then(response => {
        const myBlob = new Blob([response.data], { type: response.headers['content-type'] });
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.href = fileURL;
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

If I view the response in the console, I am getting the file data. And If I call the API using Postman, I can download the response, save and open the file with no issues.

Sample Console data:

```
data: "%PDF-1.5↵%�쏢↵9 0 obj↵<</Length 10 0 R/Filter /Fl...
```

However... when opening in the browser, it seems that the file is always corrupt or something, as nothing is displayed.

Any suggestions...?

Further to this... when I look at the original file in notepad the 1st 3 lines are

```
%PDF-1.5
%Çì¢
9 0 obj
```

But when I view in the browser and save, that file's 1st 3 lines are

```
%PDF-1.5
%�쏢
9 0 obj
```

Comment: it would have been better if you can send returning response data here.. that would be a better approach to look at the problem

Answer (score 0):

Solved by swapping out the javascript with the below. Notice I had to swap out Axios for plain old vanilla fetch.

```
fetch(`${config.apiGatewayURL}/download-file/${file}`)
    .then(response => {
        const blob = response.blob();
        blob.type = response.headers['content-type'];
        return blob;
    })
    .then(blob => {
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.href = fileURL;
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```